# Check a specific node value with SimpleXMLElement :: xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, simplexml

The following solution finds the datafield with `tag="100"` and get the value of subfield with `code="a"`. Now I realised that I also need to check if a subfield with `code="4"` exist and if so check if the value is xyz and only fetch the subfield `code="a"` value if that condition is true. How can I change the code in order to do that?

XML:

```
<datafield tag="100">
   <subfield code="a">value
   </subfield>
   <subfield code="4">xyz   
   </subfield>
</datafield>
```

code

```
 if($datafield['tag']=='100'){
            $datafield->registerXPathNamespace('foo', 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim');
            foreach( $datafield->xpath('foo:subfield') as $sf ) {
                if($sf['code']=='a'){
                    $auth=func($sf);
                }
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*[subfield[@code=4 and normalize-space()='xyz']]
                                 /subfield[@code='a']/text()
```

**Or use**:

```
string(/*[subfield[@code=4 and normalize-space()='xyz']]
                                          /subfield[@code='a'])
```

The first XPath expression above selects all text nodes children of all `subfield` children of the top element for which the value of their `code` attribute is `"a"` but only if the top element has a `subfield` child whose `code` attribute has the value `4` and whose string value after removing the leading and trailing whitespace characters is `"xyz"`

The second expression is very similar, but it directly evaluates to the string value of the first of the text nodes that are selected by the first expression.

These expressions are simpler than the ones in other answers, because no reverse axis is used at all and all predicates are specified at their most appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath to directly fetch the desired node, if all conditions apply

`/datafield[@tag='100']/subfield[@code='a'][normalize-space(../subfield[@code='4']) = 'xyz']`